# "sitemap-questions-0.xml" shows up in Google search results

Tags: support

Google seems to be finding a "sitemap-questions-0.xml" on android.stackexchange.com. However, when I go to click on it, I get a 404 error. Here's the link that Google gives me: https://android.stackexchange.com/sitemap-questions-0.xml

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is this an old result from when Googlebot did its crawling, or does the file actually exist but return a 404 to prevent regular users from trying to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the site's [Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap) - a machine-readable directory for search engines.

It's [*only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/how-does-stack-overflow-protect-its-sitemap) served to search engines, since it can be quite large and isn't particularly useful to anyone else. Normally, this wouldn't show up in Google's search results - I would expect it to disappear eventually.

Comment: Does it determine that by user agent? In other words, if I was to mimic the user agent of Googlebot, would it serve it to me?

Comment: Yes it would, @gparyani